# Transformation of contour integral $\int \frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi i z^3}-1} \operatorname dz$ over the circle $|z|=\sqrt[3]{n+\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, solution-verification

I would like to solve the following:

> $$\int\limits_{|z|=\sqrt[3]{n+\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi i z^3}-1}\operatorname dz$$

I'm given an hint: *"use a transformation $w=z^3$"*

I would make use of the following theorem:

> If $w$ holomorphic on $\Gamma$ and $f$ continous on $w(\Gamma)$ then 
>   $$\int\limits_{w(\Gamma)} f(w) \operatorname dw = \int\limits_\Gamma f(w(z)) w'(z) \operatorname dz$$

But I'm a bit confused as to the **contour** itself. Is the following right?

($\Gamma_1$ is the circle with radius $\sqrt[3]{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ and center $O$, while $\Gamma_2$ had a radius of $n+\frac{1}{2}$)

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi i z^3}-1}\operatorname dz &= \int_{\Gamma_2} \frac{w^{\frac{2}{3}}}{e^{2\pi i w}-1} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot w^{-\frac{2}{3}}\operatorname dw\\
&=  \frac{1}{3} \int_{\Gamma_2} \frac{\operatorname dw}{e^{2\pi i w}-1}\\
\end{align}$$

Using the residue theorem ($\operatorname*{res}_{w=k} f(w) = \frac{-i}{2\pi}$)

$$\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi i z^3}-1}\operatorname dz = 1$$

#### Question

This looks to good to be true ;)

Could someone verify? Have I applied the theorem right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $w=z^3$. Then since $\frac1{e^{2\pi iw}-1}$ has a residue of $\frac1{2\pi i}$ at each integer, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=\left(n+\frac12\right)^{1/3}}\frac{z^2\,\mathrm{d}z}{e^{2\pi iz^3}-1}
&=\frac13\cdot3\int_{|w|=n+\frac12}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{e^{2\pi iw}-1}\\
&=2\pi i(2n+1)\frac1{2\pi i}\\
&=2n+1
\end{align}
$$
since there are $2n+1$ integers inside $|w|=n+\frac12$. The factor of $3$ is because for each time $z$ traces the circle, $w=z^3$ circles it $3$ times.

Comment: Are you sure about the factor 3? Doesn't the factor $\frac{1}{3}$ take care of that?

Comment: @dietervdf: indeed, they cancel each other.

Comment: I'm starting to get the multiplication, but I don't see it reflected in the theorem. Could it be that $f$ isn't continuous over $w(\Gamma)$?

Comment: @dietervdf: In the integral with $z$, $z$ completes the circle once; that is, $\Gamma$ circles the singularities once. Since $w=z^3$, $w$ completes the circle three times; that is $\Gamma^3$ circles the singularities three times. So really the $3$ should be in the contour, but I wrote the contour for $w$ as a single circuit and multiplied the integral by $3$ to reflect the three revolutions.

Comment: @dietervdf: If it helps you to decide whether to invest effort to understand what I am saying, Mathematica agrees. `z[n_,t_]:=(n+1/2)^(1/3)Exp[2Pi I t]` and `f[n_]:=NIntegrate[z[n,t]^2/(Exp[2Pi I z[n,t]^3]-1)D[z[n,t],t],{t,0,1},WorkingPrecision->20]` yields `f[1]=3` and `f[4]=9` and `f[5]=11`.

Comment: I've got it. In the textbook of the course it is mentioned *"$w(\Gamma)$ is not necessarily simple, but it can be divided in simple contour's"* Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{n + 1/2}^{1/3}}
     {z^{2} \over \expo{2\pi\ic z^{3}} - 1}\,\dd z:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

> I'll perform the evaluation *without* modifying the original contour.
>   It'll use the well known expansion
>   $\ds{{1 \over \expo{w} - 1}=\sum_{n\ =\ -\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over w - 2n\pi\ic}}$.

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{n + 1/2}^{1/3}}{z^{2} \over \expo{2\pi\ic z^{3}} - 1}
\,\dd z}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{n + 1/2}^{1/3}}z^{2}\sum_{m\ =\ -n}^{n}
{1 \over 2\pi\ic z^{3} -2\pi m\ic}\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2\pi\ic}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{n + 1/2}^{1/3}}
\bracks{{1 \over z} + 2\sum_{m\ =\ 1}^{n}{z^{5} \over z^{6} - m^{2}}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&=1 + {1 \over \pi\ic}\sum_{m\ =\ 1}^{n}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{n + 1/2}^{1/3}}{z^{5} \over z^{6} - m^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&=1 + 2\sum_{m\ =\ 1}^{n}
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{5}\lim_{\atop z\ \to\ m^{1/3}\expo{k\pi\ic/3}}
\bracks{\pars{z - m^{1/3}\expo{k\pi\ic/3}}{z^{5} \over z^{6} - m^{2}}}
=1 + 2\sum_{m\ =\ 1}^{n}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{5}{1 \over 6}
\\[5mm]&=1 + 2\sum_{m\ =\ 1}^{n}1=1 + 2\times n=\color{#66f}{\LARGE 2n + 1}
\end{align}